# Get people detail from microsoft in php

Tags: php, curl, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want create php app for get login users contacts details form Microsoft(outlook).
For that I used below way but I can't proper result.

1. `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf')`
2. https://graph.microsoft.com//v1.0/me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest Microsoft Auth Way

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
but not

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf
```

More suggestion: get started from the [official docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/php) then change to your code. Do not fully write your own framework before you have already familiar with the graph product